# Counting variables in a formula

Tags: r, formula

I would like to count the number of variables that enter into the right hand side of a formula.  Is there a function that does this?

For example:

```
y<-rnorm(100)
x1<-rnorm(100)
x2<-rnorm(100)
x3<-rnorm(100)
f<-formula(y~x1+x2+x3)
```

Then, I would call `SomeFunction(f)` which would return 3 (since there are 3 x variables on the right hand side of the equation). Does SomeFunction exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of estimated parameters, as suggested by your comment below G. Grothendieck's answer, you could try the code below.  I added one to `n.coefficients` for the error term, as is done with AIC.

```
n      <- 20                                       # number of observations
B0     <-  2                                       # intercept
B1     <- -1.5                                     # slope 1
B2     <-  0.5                                     # slope 2
B3     <- -2.5                                     # slope 3
sigma2 <-  5                                       # residual variance

x1     <- sample(1:3, n, replace=TRUE)             # categorical covariate
x12    <- ifelse(x1==2, 1, 0)
x13    <- ifelse(x1==3, 1, 0)
x3     <- round(runif(n, -5 , 5), digits = 3)      # continuous covariate
eps    <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(sigma2))    # error
y      <- B0 + B1*x12 + B2*x13 + B3*x3 + eps       # dependent variable
x1     <- as.factor(x1)

model1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x3)                          # linear regression
model1

summary(model1)

n.coefficients <- as.numeric(sapply(model1, length)[1]) + 1
n.coefficients

# [1] 5
```

Here is a more straight-forward alternative to the code for `n.coefficients`:

```
# For each variable in a linear regression model, one coefficient exists
# An intercept coefficient exists as well
# Subtract -1 to account for the intercept
n.coefficients2 <- length(model1$coefficients) - 1
n.coefficients2

# [1] 5
```

Comment: The question asks about a formula, not a model.

Answer (score 8):

You might need to look at some of the related functions linked in the help page for `formula`. In particular, `terms`:

```
> terms(f)
y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4
attr(,"variables")
list(y, x1, x2, x3, x4)
attr(,"factors")
   x1 x2 x3 x4
y   0  0  0  0
x1  1  0  0  0
x2  0  1  0  0
x3  0  0  1  0
x4  0  0  0  1
attr(,"term.labels")
[1] "x1" "x2" "x3" "x4"
attr(,"order")
[1] 1 1 1 1
attr(,"intercept")
[1] 1
attr(,"response")
[1] 1
attr(,".Environment")
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Note the "term.labels" attribute.

Answer (score 7):

Here are two possibilities:

```
length(attr(terms(f), "term.labels"))

length(all.vars(update(f, z ~.))) - 1
```

Comment: Thank you! However, if I include a factor variable, it only counts as one. Is there any way around this? For example: for f<-formula(y~x+factor(months)), this would return 2.  I would like it to return 13 (one for x, plus 12 months). Or, even better would be for it to return 12 (one for x, 12 months minus one since one month factor would drop out of a linear regression).

Comment: That's a different question than the one you asked in the post.

Comment: @BUML1290 You need to update your question to get an answer about factors in formula.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between variables and terms.

Answer (score 1):

In light of your comment, this may depend on how you're fitting the model...

In the case of a linear model, these answers all give `12`:

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame (y=rnorm(100),
                   x=rnorm(100),
                   months=sample(letters[1:12], replace=TRUE, size=100))
f1 <-formula(y~x+factor(months))
l1 <- lm(f1, data=df1)
ncol(l1$qr$qr)-1
```

or

```
length(colnames(l1$qr$qr))-1
```

Here `qr` is the `QR decomposition of a matrix` as used in fitting the model. It will contain the no. of parameters of interest.

You could also find which variables are factors from the `model.frame`, such as:

```
length(unique(model.frame(l1)[["factor(months)"]]))
```

Or more generally with `.getXlevels`, which will give you a list of unique values for each factor on the predictor side, as in:

```
length( stats::.getXlevels(terms(l1), model.frame(l1))[[1]] )
```

*Update*

@Mark Miller was barking up a better tree. If your model has an `AIC`-type method available, you should be able to use this to get the no. of parameters. 
For a `lm`, it's a hidden S3 method in `stats`, so call it like this:

```
stats:::extractAIC.lm(l1)[[1]] -1
```